# How to make ".bat" file use certain text file's text as a command

Tags: java, android, windows, batch-file

I am writing a script that can deodex files.
I won't say much still it's a WIP have a look at this part of my bat file

```
if %2 equ jar (
set/a numdeox += 1
echo [*] [FW File: %numdeox% of %total%]Now Deodexing %~n1.%2 
) else if %2 equ apk (
set/a numdeoxa += 1
echo - [APP: %numdeoxa% of %totala%]Now deodexing %~n1.%2 
)

echo [*] Changing %~n1.odex to classes.dex, please wait...
java -jar baksmali.jar -a 19 -T ../../tools/inline.txt -d ../temp_framework -x %1
java -jar smali.jar -a 19 setapi.txt out -o classes.dex

del %1 /Q
rd out /Q /S
echo [*] Merging %~n1.%2 and classes.dex ,please wait...
7z.exe a -tzip %~n1.%2 classes.dex>nul
del classes.dex /Q
cd ..\..\
```

Have a look at line 'java jar baksmali.jar -a 19 -T ../../tools/inline.txt -d ../temp_framework -x %1'
here the api is 19. I made a txt file called "setapi.txt" and asked that whatever value user will enter in the text file will be automatically be set as api in this batch script. Now my problem is what command or line to add in place of **19** so that whatever number user enters in the .txt file it is read by Windows
for eg-
**java -jar baksmali.jar -a (command here) ../../tools/inline.txt -d ../temp_framework -x %1**

If anyone can help I'll be obliged thanks! Or if someone can suggest some other alternative for this API thing.

Comment: Can you include a sample of what `setapi.txt` would normally look like?

Comment: Setapi.txt is a normal text file. I just created it normally by right click -> new -> new text file and renamed it as setapi.txt

Answer (score 2):

If the .txt file only contains what you want you could just use...

```
set /p API=<setapi.txt
```

However if the setapi.txt contains more than what you want I would use a variable substring after the previous code...

```
set API=%API:~5, -1%
```

If setapi.txt contained this string

API="JAVA"

then the previous code would return just JAVA inside your variable.

For more info on set /p [look here](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html)

For more info on variable substring [look here](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html)

Comment: thanks! I am kind of a newbie at this can you please merge it all in one sentence and write the output please

Comment: The file is in location C:\Universal_MTK\Deodex\tools\setapi.txt how to imply this command in the example please help. setapi.txt has only ONE numerical value like 19 or 20 or 21

Comment: set /p API=<C:\Universal_MTK\Deodex\tools\setapi.txt    That will assign your number value in setapi.txt to the variable API to use the variable you must surround it in % as in %API%

Comment: it is not working windows is saying cannot find file path specified

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this (assuming the file contains only a single line)

```
set API=
FOR /F %%i in (setapi.txt) do (
    set API=%%i
)
echo API=%API%
...
java -jar baksmali.jar -a %API% -T ../../tools/inline.txt -d ../temp_framework -x %1
java -jar smali.jar -a %API% setapi.txt out -o classes.dex
```

**edit** to set the variable API have a look on the solution of @Randy Rakestraw. It's the smarter way then using the FOR loop.

Comment: It worked! But there is a new problem, actually this command is supposedly to come in a single line and now it shows error -T is not an acceptable command

Comment: @YaMan I added the amended lines of your script. Otherwise don't suppress the command output to see how the lines are executed. I'm really sure there is a typo somewhere. I have tested the above code and it works for the `setapi.txt` file without line break after the number, with CRLF and with LF.